# Error: Failed to start application: Class 'JSessionHandlerJoomla' not found in joomla

Tags: joomla

my live site in this Error: Failed to start application Class 'JSessionHandlerJoomla' not found

Answer (score -1):

You must have changed servers ...
There are some cases ...
Install the PHP modules.

Update your Joomla